# How do you rollback/downgrade a docker container/image to a previous version?

Tags: docker-compose

I'm a total noob and the search engine results I get only tell me how to downgrade docker itself. I'm still learning what the basic terms like *"image", "container", "flags", "commands"*, etc., reference. I searched for things like *"docker-compose downgrade image --install --upgrade"*.

I'm running this open source email program https://github.com/knadh/listmonk via docker. With difficulty, I patched together [the general commands to set it up and use it via hosting](https://gist.github.com/MaximilianKohler/e5158fcfe6de80a9069926a67afcae11) on an ubuntu server and installing with docker.

I ran into some bugs with a recent release and need to roll back to a previous version. The developer said he's not familiar with docker commands. [Full discussion here](https://github.com/knadh/listmonk/issues/1457).

[Here are the commands I've guessed at](https://github.com/knadh/listmonk/issues/1457#issuecomment-1679784408), but they're not correct.

During my searches, I saw information suggesting that previous versions don't need to be "reinstalled", but they're "present" already, and all you have to do is change the value in the `docker-compose.yml` file? So for Step 4 I would skip `sudo docker-compose run --rm app ./listmonk --install` completely?

If so, does it only work that way for versions I've upgraded from in the past *(and thus are still "installed")*? And if I wanted to run another one I'd have to use some other command(s)?

For step 1, is `sudo docker-compose down app` the correct command instead of `sudo docker-compose down`? That way it only stops "app" and leaves nginx, db, and certbot running?

`sudo docker container ls` gives me `certbot, ubuntu_nginx_1, listmonk_app, listmonk_db`, and I restart them with `sudo docker-compose restart app db nginx certbot`.

Example/default `docker-compose.yml` https://github.com/knadh/listmonk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

I'm scared about screwing things up, so I don't want to experiment with commands that I don't know are correct.

Also, I think the commands are not universal? For example, I found [other possible options](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/upgrading/), including:

```
--upgrade, -u, --recreate | Upgrade if service has changed
--force-upgrade, --force-recreate | Upgrade regardless if service has changed
--confirm-upgrade, -c | Confirm that the upgrade was success and delete old containers
--rollback, -r | Rollback to the previous deployed version
```

But I think they may not apply to the software (Listmonk) I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

The important line in the `docker-compose.yml` file is

```yaml
image: listmonk/listmonk:latest
```

The `latest` tag at the end of the line says what version of the image to use.  Note that `latest` isn't special other than being a default value: if you have an image tagged `latest` locally, Docker will use it, and if not, it will find the thing on Docker Hub currently tagged as `latest`, but it won't update the image if you already have a `latest` image locally.

If you look at the [image's Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/listmonk/listmonk) you can find the list of image tags.  If you need to revert to Listmonk 2.4.0, that's easy: change the image to

```yaml
image: listmonk/listmonk:2.4.0
```

and then tell Compose to update (recreate) the containers

```yaml
docker-compose up -d
```

This matches what's in your write-up.  One-off `docker-compose run` commands will use the updated `image:` line as well.  The write-up discusses some things like resetting the database content (which is what the `listmonk --install` step seems to do) that are a little outside the scope of Docker.  Generically, I might suggest running the "down" migrations from the newer image before you downgrade, but that write-up doesn't suggest any particular migration system.